# React useEffect not updating state for redirect to secured route after JWT authentication

Tags: reactjs, jwt

I've created a secured route /secret, using react router inside my react app, when someone logins then my app creates a cookie through jwt and stores it in user's browser, when someone hits this /secret route then my frontend shares information of token with my backend and verify if it is valid or not (using jwt.verify) and if it is verified my backend responds with status 200 and my frontend will grant it the permission to view /secret, and if the user is not verified he will be redirected to /login route to login again. I've used useState to set the redirect value to true using useEffect hook of react, but my setRedirect is not updating the redirect variable and due to this I will never able to view the /secret route, instead it always redirect me to /login page.

This is my code on react component
**/SECRET**

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Navigate } from "react-router-dom";

export default function SecretPage() {
    const [redirect, setRedirect] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
    async function authChecker() {
        try {
            const response = await fetch("http://localhost:4000/authenticate", {
                credentials: "include",
            });

            if (response.ok) {
                setRedirect(true); //IT IS NOT UPDATING
            } else {
                console.error('Authentication failed:', response.statusText);
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error checking authentication:', error);
            // Handle error
        }
    }

    authChecker();
}, []);

if (!redirect) {
    return <Navigate to="/login" state={{ message: "You are not logged in, please login" }} />;
}

return (
    <h1>SecretPage</h1>
);
}
```

and this is my backend function on route http://localhost:4000/authenticate

```
app.get("/authenticate", (req, res) => {
const token = req.cookies.jwt;
if (token) {
    jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET, (err, decoded) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error('Error verifying token:', err);
            return res.status(401).json({ message: 'Unauthorized' });
        } else {
            // Token is valid, allow access to protected resource
            return res.status(200).json({ message: 'Access granted' });
        }
    });
} else {
    res.status(401).json({ message: 'Unauthorized' });
}
});
```

Comment: `redirect` is initially false and on the initial render the `Navigate` component is rendered. The `useEffect` hook never has a chance to update the state because the component already got navigated away from and unmounted. Use a loading condition while you are computing/verifying the auth state.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you redirect variable start with 0, you have to understand that your API response is not immediate, but your render does, making your if block rendering your Redirect commponent immediately.

I suggest using another useState to solve this:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Navigate } from "react-router-dom";

export default function SecretPage() {
    const [redirect, setRedirect] = useState(false);
    const [done, setDone] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
    async function authChecker() {
        try {
            const response = await fetch("http://localhost:4000/authenticate", {
                credentials: "include",
            });

            if (response.ok) {
                setRedirect(true); //IT IS NOT UPDATING
            } else {
                console.error('Authentication failed:', response.statusText);
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error checking authentication:', error);
            // Handle error
        }
        setDone(true)
    }

    authChecker();
}, []);


if (!done) {
   return <div>Loading...</div>; 
}    

if (!redirect) {
    return <Navigate to="/login" state={{ message: "You are not logged in, please login" }} />;
}

return (
    <h1>SecretPage</h1>
);
}
```